# Convert Json data into SQL table using Python

Tags: python, sql, json

My json data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "fields": {
            "bkdate": null,
            "business_credit_card_total_balances": null,
            "business_credit_card_total_limits": null,
            "business_total_monthly_debt_payments": null,
            "business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments": null,
            "created_at": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
            "detail_results": null,
            "error_reason": "no reasons",
            "fico_v2": "695",
            "fico_v3": null,
            "loanapp_id": 194,
            "personal_credit_card_total_balances": null,
            "personal_credit_card_total_limits": null,
            "personal_total_monthly_payments": null,
            "report_type": "CreditProfile",
            "result": true,
            "role": "applicant",
            "total_mortgage_monthly_payments": null,
            "username": "cho",
            "version": "CF Microloan",
            "xml_data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?><NetConnectResponse xmlns=\"http://www.experian.com/NetConnectResponse\"><CompletionCode>0000</CompletionCode>"
        },
        "model": "common.prequalresult",
        "pk": 1
    }
]
```

I Want to convert it into SQL table. I tried this:

```
v = pd.DataFrame(data['fields'])
t = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['fields'], ['model'], ['pk'], meta_prefix='parent_')

v.to_sql('fields', engine)
t.to_sql('fields', engine)
```

But it does not work. Can someone work it and output the SQL table?

My errors looks like this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-a186308b321b> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 v = pd.DataFrame(data['fields'])
      3 t = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['fields'], ['model'], ['pk'], meta_prefix='parent_')
      4 
      5 v.to_sql('fields', engine)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I want to create two tables. One include 'fields', 'model' and 'pk'.And another table include all the values in 'fields'.

The schema looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE8ju.png)

Comment: what error it is showing?

Comment: Please add more specific detail about your problem (for example what is not working? what is the error log ...)

Comment: I want to create two tables. One include 'fields', 'model' and 'pk'.And another table include all the values in 'fields'. The error is ```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-a186308b321b> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 v = pd.DataFrame(data['fields'])
      3 t = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['fields'], ['model'], ['pk'], meta_prefix='parent_')
      4 
      5 v.to_sql('fields', engine)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: Is `data['fields']` string type? If it is, `v = pd.DataFrame(data['fields'])` will make error

Comment: question is not properly explained.... which are the fields you want to insert into table?

Comment: data['fields'] is a dictionary. See my data above.

Comment: error is showing because you are accessing list with str index... your data should be like, ```data[0]['fields']```. try this

Comment: I want to convert the data into SQL table, but have no idea. Could you give some suggestion ?

Comment: can you provide the schema of SQL tables which you want as output from JSON?

Comment: I add a link in description. I am not sure it is right.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data which you want to store in Mysql DB. You can use a One-to-One relationship for storing in DB. Instead of using pandas DataFrame it can be handled properly using `SQLAlchemy` ORM. The following code gives a better understanding to solve this issue. Right now I have considered only few keys from `fields` key.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text, DateTime, Float, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

total_data = [
    {
        "fields": {
            "bkdate": None,
            "business_credit_card_total_balances": None,
            "created_at": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
        },
        "model": "common.prequalresult",
        "pk": 1
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "bkdate": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
            "business_credit_card_total_balances": 23,
            "created_at": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
        },
        "model": "common.prequalresult",
        "pk": 2
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "bkdate": "asdfas",
            "business_credit_card_total_balances": 1111,
            "created_at": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
        },
        "model": "common.prequalresult",
        "pk": 3
    }
]

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost:5432/my_data', echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)
    model = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    child = relationship('Comment', backref='article', uselist=False)


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    bkdate = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    business_credit_card_total_balances = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))


x = Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for temp_data in total_data:
    pk = temp_data['pk']
    model = temp_data['model']
    bkdate = temp_data['fields']['bkdate']
    business_credit_card_total_balances = temp_data['fields']['business_credit_card_total_balances']
    created_at = temp_data['fields']['created_at']
    parent1 = Article(pk=temp_data['pk'], model=model)
    child = Comment(bkdate=bkdate,
                    business_credit_card_total_balances=business_credit_card_total_balances,
                    created_at=created_at,
                    article=parent1)

    session.add(parent1)
    session.add(child)

session.commit()
```

As field pk given in each dict can be duplicated, so I have created id as a primary key.

Output:

```
mysql> select * from article;
+----+------+----------------------+
| id | pk   | model                |
+----+------+----------------------+
|  1 |    1 | common.prequalresult |
|  2 |    2 | common.prequalresult |
|  3 |    3 | common.prequalresult |
+----+------+----------------------+

mysql> select * from comment;
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------+
| id | bkdate                   | business_credit_card_total_balances | created_at               | article_id |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------+
|  1 | NULL                     |                                NULL | 2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z |          1 |
|  2 | 2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z |                                  23 | 2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z |          2 |
|  3 | asdfas                   |                                1111 | 2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z |          3 |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I run the code. But it shows the erorr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'. I tried:pip install pymysql and I am using Google Colab.

Comment: Use pip install pymysql. Also install sqlalchemy in python